examples of weights of representations
I'm studying weights of representations. But I'm having a hard time seeing the example given in the textbook. Here are some basic concepts written in the book:

Consider $GL(W)$, whose elements do not commute. However, we can try
to salvage as much as possible by choosing a largest possible
subgroup $T \subset GL(W)$ where this idea does work. A maximal
abelian diagonalizable subgroup $T \subset GL(W)$ is called a maximal
torus of $GL(W)$. After having made this choice, for any
representation $\rho : GL(W) \rightarrow GL(V)$, $V$ can be decomposed
into eigenspaces for $T$. These eigenspaces will be called weight
spaces and the corresponding eigenvalues for these eigenspaces
$\lambda : T \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ are called the weights of
$V$. Lie's theorem guarantees that the elements of $\rho(T)$ are
simultaneously diagonalizable.

Then the author provided an example

Choose a basis $e_1, \ldots, e_w$ of $W$ and parametrize $T$ by $$T =
 \left\{ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}x_1 & & 0 \\& \ddots & \\
       0 & & x_w
         \end{array} \right) \mid x_j \in \mathbb{C}^* \right\}.
     $$ Then, $e_1$ is a weight vector with weight $x_1$, $e_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes e_w$ is a weight vector with weight $x_1^{i_1} \cdots
> x_w^{i_w}$, and $e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_2 \otimes e_1$ is a weight vector
with weight $x_1 x_2$. On the other hand, $e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_1
> \otimes e_3$ is not a weight vector.

Why would $x_1$, $x_1 x_2$, and $x_1^{i_1} \cdots x_w^{i_w}$ be weights? According to the definition, it supposed to be a linear function from $T$ to $C^*$ with weight space $W_{x_1}:=\{w\in W| \forall t\in T, \rho(t)w = x_1(t) w\}$. What exactly is $x_1(t)$ for example?

$x_i$ is the function sending a matrix in $T$ to the $i^{th}$ diagonal entry, namely the entry $x_i$. This is a character, and any product of such functions is also a character.

A weight is not a linear function but a group homomorphism $T\to\mathbb{C}^*$.
In the example given, $x_1$ is meant to be the function which assigns to a diagonal matrix its top left entry. When you multiply $e_1$ by a diagonal matrix $D$ you get $\rho(t)e_1=x_1(D)e_1$.
I hope that helps.
